# Oracle foreign key constraints - check constraint syntax?

Tags: oracle, key, constraints

I have a child table in oracle that has two foreign key columns, relating to two different parent tables. I want to create a constraint that says the child must have at least one of those parents - e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
   FOREIGN KEY (column1)
   REFERENCES parent_table (column1)
   OR
   FOREIGN KEY (column2)
   REFERENCES parent_table_2 (column1)
```

This won't work with a foreign key constraint because that can only  relate to one parent table - is it possible to do this with a check constraint instead?

Comment: in this scenario, check constraint not possible. better try with trigger

Comment: What happens for example if `column1` matches `parent_table.column1`? Is `column2` NULL in this case or may it have an arbitrary value?

Comment: One column can be null, or both columns can be populated. But one foreign key column must be populated. It's an interesting database design that I did not design, I'm just trying to create some checks for relational integrity in the database

Comment: Thanks Gaj, I'll try with a trigger

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key constraints ensure the referential integrity, not mandatory values.
I think you have to have to separate FK contraints and additional check constraint like this:

```
alter table table_name 
    add constraint c_check_cols 
        check(column1 is not null or column2 is not null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name_1
   FOREIGN KEY (column1)
   REFERENCES parent_table (column1);

ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name_2
   FOREIGN KEY (column2)
   REFERENCES parent_table_2 (column1);

ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name_3
        check (COALESCE(column1, column2) IS NOT NULL);
```

Of course for `column1` and `column2` column you must permit `NULL` values.